# What does the shortcut picture with x within bounded right arrow mean?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut

This is the shortcut I am interested in:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **Forward Delete** (on Windows keyboards called **Del**). You can achieve it on MacBook keyboard with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd>.